# Modelless form redirect url not working cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, php-7.2, cakephp-3.6

I have a user login form that is not in the login.ctp file. It's in my default layout, therefore I had to clearly specify the login url in the $this->Form->create like so:

```
$this->Form->create(null, array('url' => ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']));
```

Because of this When I have the **redirect** query string in a url like:

```
/users/login?redirect=%2Flistings%2Fview%2F56
```

The user is not redirected to the page (mydomain.com/listings/56 as in the above redirect)

I can't just remove the **url** key from Form->create because if I do so, let's say that I'm on About Us page, then the action for the form will be wrong, it will be:

```
action="/pages/about"
```

It's supposed to be:

```
action="/users/login"
```

Any idea how I can fix this please?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. Is your problem that you can't generate URLs like `/users/login?redirect%2Flistings%2Fview%2F56` in your layout? Or that your login function doesn't obey the redirect after login when you do?

Comment: If you're using modelless form then you need to specify form object when creating the form instead of just putting `null`. Please refer this URL for more info https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/form.html#creating-a-form.